# How to reduce multiple joins in spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 2.4.1, to figure out some ratios on my data frame.

Where I need to find different ratio factors of ratios, different columns in given data frame(`df_data`) by joining to meta dataframe (i.e. `resDs`).

I am getting these ratio factors (i.e. `ratio_1_factor`, `ratio_2_factor` & `ratio_3_factor`)  by using three different joins with different join conditions i.e. `joinedDs` , `joinedDs2`, `joinedDs3`

Is there any other alternative to reduce the number of joins ?? make it work optimum?

You can find the entire sample data in the below public URL.

https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1165111237342523/3521103084252405/7035720262824085/latest.html

**How to handle multi-steps instead of single step in when clause:**

```
.withColumn("step_1_ratio_1", (col("ratio_1").minus(lit(0.00000123))).cast(DataTypes.DoubleType)) // step-2
      .withColumn("step_2_ratio_1", (col("step_1_ratio_1").multiply(lit(0.02))).cast(DataTypes.DoubleType)) //step-3
      .withColumn("step_3_ratio_1", (col("step_2_ratio_1").divide(col("step_1_ratio_1"))).cast(DataTypes.DoubleType)) //step-4
      .withColumn("ratio_1_factor", (col("ratio_1_factor")).cast(DataTypes.DoubleType)) //step-5
```

i.e. "ratio_1_factor" calucated based on various other columns in the dataframe , df_data

these steps -2,3,4 , are being used in other ratio_factors calculation too. i.e. ratio_2_factor, ratio_2_factor
how this should be handled ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join one time and calculate  `ratio_1_factor`, `ratio_2_factor` and `ratio_3_factor` columns using `max` and `when` function in aggregation :

```scala
val joinedDs = df_data.as("aa")
  .join(
    broadcast(resDs.as("bb")),
    col("aa.g_date").between(col("bb.start_date"), col("bb.end_date"))
  )
  .groupBy("item_id", "g_date", "ratio_1", "ratio_2", "ratio_3")
  .agg(
    max(when(
        col("aa.ratio_1").between(col("bb.A"), col("bb.A_lead")),
        col("ratio_1").multiply(lit(0.1))
      )
    ).cast(DoubleType).as("ratio_1_factor"),
    max(when(
        col("aa.ratio_2").between(col("bb.A"), col("bb.A_lead")),
        col("ratio_2").multiply(lit(0.2))
      )
    ).cast(DoubleType).as("ratio_2_factor"),
    max(when(
        col("aa.ratio_3").between(col("bb.A"), col("bb.A_lead")),
        col("ratio_3").multiply(lit(0.3))
      )
    ).cast(DoubleType).as("ratio_3_factor")
  )


joinedDs.show(false)

//+-------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+
//|item_id|g_date    |ratio_1  |ratio_2    |ratio_3    |ratio_1_factor       |ratio_2_factor|ratio_3_factor|
//+-------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+
//|50312  |2016-01-04|0.0456646|0.046899415|0.046000415|0.0045664600000000005|0.009379883   |0.0138001245  |
//+-------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: thank you so much , i have one more doubt , in the "when" clause if i need to handle multi-steps instead of one i.e. col("ratio_x").multiply(lit(0.x)) , how to handle it. these multi-steps i.e. new column values are also used to other ratio columns i.e. ratio_1_factor , ratio_2_factor & ratio_3_factor . I have updated the new query , can you please advice.

Comment: @BdEngineer what is the problem if you write simply like this : `.withColumn("ratio_1_factor", (col("ratio_1") - lit(0.00000123)) * lit(0.02) / (col("ratio_1") - lit(0.00000123)))` ? There is no problem using it like this with `when`. You need just to simplify the expression, the logic behind the when expressions is the same.

Comment: what are the steps/ways to write queries like this , how should develop skills like you ? how you got this though to write... still i am struggling to use agg funcations properly ... some fundamental stuff i am missing ... plz help ... sir , i have one use-case like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66635632/joining-mulitple-dataframes-based-on-joined-dataframe-column-null-or-not       Can you advice how to approach it ?