# joining mulitple dataframes based on joined-dataframe column null or not

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v.
I have a scenario where I need to join two dataframe say df1, df2.
Where I have a joining condition which uses SQL **nvl(max(df2.col_n), min(df1.col_n))** function.

Unfortunately nvl() function resulting to error like
**Correlated sub query column in SPARK SQL is not allowed as part of a non-equality predicate**

Hence decided to have two more dfs df3, df4 for getting min_rate_date and max_rate_date like something below to replace nvl like functionality

```
df3 = df2.groupBy(col("data_date"),col("code"))
         .agg(min(col("rate_date")).as("min_rate_date"))

df4 = df2.groupBy(col("data_date"),col("code"))
         .agg(max(col("rate_date")).as("max_rate_date"))
```

df5 = df3.join(df4);

now i have to join back to get final_df

ie. `final_df = df1.join(df5)`

is there any alternative to optimize this ?

let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Could you show the SQL query that led to the error shown? It should be possible to use nvl in a join, but not in a correlated subquery.

Comment: final String query = """ select * from source_tab source ,ex_tab ex where source.currency_code =  ex.base_code 
           and  ex.rate_date = source.date 
             and  ex.rate_date = nvl( 
              ( select max(ex2.rate_date) from ex_tab ex2 where ex2.base_code  =  ex.base_code and  ex2.rate_date < source.date )
             , ( select min(ex2.rate_date) from ex_tab ex2 where ex2.base_code  =  ex.base_code and ex2.rate_date >= source.date ) 
            ) 
      """
         ;

Comment: I guess doing two joins is fine. If you use correlated subqueries, it's doing a join behind the scenes, so there shouldn't be much difference as long as you managed to get correct results